# Can the relevant log entries be included in Alert emails from Google Cloud Monitoring?

Tags: google-cloud-logging, google-cloud-monitoring

I have a Google Cloud Monitoring custom Metric that measures "errors of interest" in Google Cloud logs for my project, but the Alert emails it generates (threshold > 0) have only generic information, and nothing that's actually specific to the log entry(ies) that are measured by the metric.

Ideally I'd like to have these alert emails include the actual log entries captured by the metric (i.e. the specific log messages that triggered the alert), so I can see the log info right there in the alert email without having to dig through the logs. The "View Incident" and "View Logs" buttons only get me part-way there (still no details about the specific log entries in question).

**Is it possible to have these emails include the details of the log entries that triggered the alert?**

*Example alert email:*

[image]